# 'LocalOutlierFactor' object has no attribute 'negative_outlier_factor'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Herein is my setup for LOF score:

```
## Calculate each sample contrarian outlier score
outfactor=lof.negative_outlier_factor_
## Standardize the score
radius=(outfactor.max()-outfactor)/(outfactor.max()-outfactor.min())
iris.plot(kind="scatter",x="SepalWidthCm",y="PetalWidthCm",c="r",figsize=(10,6),label="data")
plt.scatter(iris["SepalWidthCm"],iris["PetalWidthCm"],s=800*radius,edgecolors="k",facecolors="none",label="LOF score")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.title("outliers score visualization")
plt.show()
```

and the error message appears as:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4140/2903391628.py in <module>
      1 ## Calculate each sample contrarian outlier score
----> 2 outfactor=lof.negative_outlier_factor
      3 ## Standardize the score
      4 radius=(outfactor.max()-outfactor)/(outfactor.max()-outfactor.min())
      5 iris.plot(kind="scatter",x="SepalWidthCm",y="PetalWidthCm",c="r",figsize=(10,6),label="data")

AttributeError: 'LocalOutlierFactor' object has no attribute 'negative_outlier_factor'
```

I have no clue how to deal with it because the LOF has been loaded.

Comment: There should be an underscore at the end.

Comment: Please see th coding, I have added the underscore

Comment: AttributeError: 'LocalOutlierFactor' object has no attribute 'negative_outlier_factor_'

Comment: Anything else seems to be missing from `dir(lof)`?

Comment: Is there any error related to compatible issues raised by the sklearn version after 1.0? cause while I us the tsne domentionality reduction, it also raised some problems!